# How to correctly log standard events with AppEventsLogger.logEvent()?

Tags: react-native-fbsdk

I've completed all the steps at configuration, created a number of events that are logged as follows:

```
import { AppEventsLogger } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
...
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('FBSDKAppEventNameAddedToWishlist');
```

and I'm able to then receive these events in Facebook Event Manager, as seen in the screenshot below
[image: Facebook Event Manager screenshot]

Our marketing team, though, claims they can only see auto-logged events, like `AppInstalls`, but not seeing those named `FBSDK...`.

Is there another, **correct** way to log these events that I'm missing or is it more likely to be an integration issue?

I didn't find any examples of how to correctly log these standard events from `react-native-fbsdk`.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook sure doesn't make it simple for their own framework to dispatch their own standard events. As seen in Javascript SDK docs,

> All predefined event names are under `FB.AppEvents.EventNames`

Yet `AppEventsLogger` imported from `react-native-fbsdk` does not have `EventNames` property. Ergo, the easiest way to find these names is to link Javascript SDK to a web page and log `FB.AppEvents.EventNames`.

Only then it is possible to map them and use in react-native. Enums are as follows:

```
ACHIEVED_LEVEL: "fb_mobile_level_achieved",
ADDED_PAYMENT_INFO: "fb_mobile_add_payment_info",
ADDED_TO_CART: "fb_mobile_add_to_cart",
ADDED_TO_WISHLIST: "fb_mobile_add_to_wishlist",
COMPLETED_REGISTRATION: "fb_mobile_complete_registration",
COMPLETED_TUTORIAL: "fb_mobile_tutorial_completion",
INITIATED_CHECKOUT: "fb_mobile_initiated_checkout",
PAGE_VIEW: "fb_page_view",
RATED: "fb_mobile_rate",
SEARCHED: "fb_mobile_search",
SPENT_CREDITS: "fb_mobile_spent_credits",
UNLOCKED_ACHIEVEMENT: "fb_mobile_achievement_unlocked",
VIEWED_CONTENT: "fb_mobile_content_view",
```